# Why am I getting "cat: write error: Broken pipe" rarely and not always

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cat, broken-pipe

I am running some scripts with commands having `cat` pipelined with `grep` like:

```
cat file.txt | grep "pattern"
```

Most of the times there are no problems. But sometimes I get below error:

> cat: write error: Broken pipe

So how do I find out when the command is causing this problem and why?

Comment: What it the content of `file.txt`, is it a growing file?

Comment: @Inian, No it's a read-only file and is never changed any time.

Comment: The reason is because the pipe is closed by `grep` when it still has some data to be read from `cat`. The signal `SIGPIPE` is caught by `cat` and it exits

Comment: @Inian, Yeah I know that can be a possible cause, but how can pipe be closed by grep before cat completes and why is this happening rarely?

Comment: Not sure which version of `grep` and `bash` shell you are running. It is not easily reproducible. For possible fixes I would suggest removing `cat` usage and do just `grep "pattern" file` to avoid the pipeline altogether

Comment: If you were running `grep -n 3`, that would cause it (when there are less than 3 matches, and the last is not near the end of the file).

Comment: However, **you shouldn't ever run `cat file.txt | grep` in the first place**. It's extremely inefficient compared to `grep -e "pattern" file.txt`, or `grep -e "pattern" <file.txt`.

Comment: This happened to me when connecting from VSCode. I had a tac - grep combination in a shell script. When I run the script from VSCode I received this error. I didn't get the error (or warning since it doesn't break the script) with ssh connection from classic terminal (Windows powershell).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is because the pipe is closed by `grep` when it still has some data to be read from `cat`. The signal `SIGPIPE` is caught by cat and it exits.

What usually happens in a pipeline is the shell runs `cat` in one process and `grep` in another. The stdout of `cat` is connected to the write-end of the pipe and stdin of `grep` to the read end. What happened was `grep` hit a pattern search that did not exist and exited immediately causing the read end of the pipe to be closed, which `cat` does not like since it has some more data to be write out to the pipe. Since the write actions happens to an other which has been closed other end, `SIGPIPE` is caught by the `cat` on which it immediately exits.

For such a trivial case, you could remove the pipeline usage altogether and run it as `grep "pattern" file.txt` when the file's contents are made available over the stdin of `grep` on which it could read from.

Comment: This depends on the version right? I've created a file with 31948800 lines of "y" and one last line with "x". When executing, `cat file | grep x`, grep waits until cat finishes. Same happens with `(echo 4; sleep 5; echo 5) | grep 5`

Comment: "hit a pattern search that did not exist"? How does it know that without reading all the way to the end? (I need to assume that the OP's *real* use case is using `grep -q`, `grep -n`, or another argument they elided from the question).

Answer (score -1):

You can use only grep without pipe like this :

```
grep "pattern" file.txt
```

I think it's better to resolve this problem